# Generating an infinite list of items does not "pause" when getting external input

Tags: f#

I have some code which I'm expecting to pause when it asks for user input. It only does this however, if the last expression is Seq.initInfinite.

```
let consoleaction (i : int) =
      Console.WriteLine ("Enter Input: ")
      (Console.ReadLine().Trim(), i)

Seq.initInfinite (fun i -> consoleaction i) |> Seq.map (fun f -> printfn "%A" f)

printfn "foo" // program will not pause unless this line is commented out.
```

Very new to F# and I've spent way too much time on this already. Would like to know what is going on :)

Comment: What do you mean with "not pause"? Sequences are lazy. Your sequence element generator function never gets invoked as you never draw from the sequence.

Comment: Also, nothing can ever get printed as you read are trying to read an infinite amount of input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try that piece of code in F# interactive you will see different effects depending on how you execute it.

For instance if you execute it in one shot it will create values but nothing will be executed since the `Seq.initInfinite` instruction is 'lost' I mean, not let-bound to anything and at the same time is a lazy expression so its side effects will not be executed. If you remove the last instruction it will start prompting, that's because fsi bounds to `it` the last expression so in order to show you the value of `it` it starts evaluating the seq expression.

Things are different if you put this in a function, for example:

```
open System
let myProgram() =
    let consoleaction ...
```

Now you will get a warning on the `Seq.initInfinite`:

```
warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has type
'seq<unit>'. Use 'ignore' to discard the result of the expression, or 
'let' to bind the result to a name.
```

Which is very clear. Additionally to `ignore` as the warning suggest you can change the `Seq.map` to `Seq.iter` since you are not interested in the result of the map which will be a seq of units.

But now again your program will not execute (try `myProgram()`)unless you remove the last line, the `printfn` and it's clear why, this is because it returns the last expression which is not the `Seq.initInfinite` which is lost since it's lazy and ignored.

If you remove the `printfn` it will become the 'return value' of your function so it will be evaluated when calling the function.